# PHP email and url validation

Tags: php, html, css

So I've made myself a little contact form with php, css, and html. But when I try to add a email validation it still sends the email and doesn't change the style of the input to red (Like I would like it to). Another issue I'm having is the button redirecting to the top of the page (which I do not want it to do). Last I can I make the input keep the text rather than remove it once submitted

HTML:

```
<div id="contact">
        <div class="container"> 
            <form id="contact-form" method="post">
            <h1>Contact Form</h1>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your Name" type="text" name="name" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="email" id="email-input" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your Phone Number (optional)" type="tel" name="phone" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <input placeholder="Your Web Site (optional)" type="url" name="site" required>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <textarea placeholder="Type your message here...." name="message" required></textarea>
            </fieldset>
            <fieldset>
                <button type="submit" id="contact-submit" name="submit">Submit</button>
            </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

PHP:

```
<?php 
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $visitors_site = $_POST['site'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $email_from = 'mattmowen1@gmail.com';
        $email_subject = 'New Contact Submission';

        $to = 'mattmowen1@gmail.com';
        $headers = "From:" . $email;
        $headers = "Contact Submission From: " . $email;
        $message1 = "Name: " . $name;
        $message2 = "\n\nEmail: " . $email;
        $message3 = "\n\nPhone: " . $phone;
        $message4 = "\n\nTheir Site: " . $visitors_site;
        $message5 = "\n\nMessage: " . $message;
        $email_body = $message1 . $message2 . $message3 . $message4 . $message5;

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
            mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);            
        } else {
            echo "<style>#email-input {color:red}</style";
        }
?>
```

Comment: @bc2946088 `filter_var()` does **not** return `true` if it's valid; it returns the filtered value, if valid. Which, in some cases, could be `0` or some other 'falsy' value. So you have to explicitly test it doesn't return `false` with `false !== filter_var( /* etc. */ )`.

Comment: Ahh, I see, in my simple test of valid and invalid, it worked perfectly fine. Thanks for the explanation.  I'll remove my comment for clarity. @DecentDabbler

Comment: Thanks for your question Matt, however for the future I'd like to ask you to split up your questions since you are basically asking three questions simultaneously now. See [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39224/354720) for clarification as to why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** for email validation in php

```
<?php 

if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $phone = $_POST['phone'];
        $visitors_site = $_POST['site'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        $email_from = 'mattmowen1@gmail.com';
        $email_subject = 'New Contact Submission';

        $to = 'mattmowen1@gmail.com';
        $headers = "From:" . $email;
        $headers = "Contact Submission From: " . $email;
        $message1 = "Name: " . $name;
        $message2 = "\n\nEmail: " . $email;
        $message3 = "\n\nPhone: " . $phone;
        $message4 = "\n\nTheir Site: " . $visitors_site;
        $message5 = "\n\nMessage: " . $message;
        $email_body = $message1 . $message2 . $message3 . $message4 . $message5;

        if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
          mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);
        } else {
          echo "<style>#email-input {color:red}</style>";
        }
}
?>
```

As per our chat conversation. I am adding jquery ajax function according to your form requirement. 
You need to create new file `email.php` and put your php code into this separate php file

```
<script>
    var url = 'email.php';
    $.ajax({
        url : url,
        type : "POST",
        dataType : "JSON",
        data : $('#contact-form').serialize(),
        success : function(response) {
            if (response.error == 0) { // success
                $('#contact-form')[0].reset();
                alert('Form submitted successfully. We will contact you asap.');
            } else { // error
                $('#email-input').css('color', 'red');//in case of email error
                alert('ERROR MESSAGE');//form is invalid
            }
        }
    })

</script>
```

To handle JSON request you need to send JSON object in response. So change you php code snippet like this:

```
if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) === false) {
  mail($to, $email_subject, $email_body,$headers);
  exit(json_encode(array('error' => 0)));
} else {
  exit(json_encode(array('error' => 1)));
}
```

Comment: Nope. The style becomes red even without submitting. But it didn't send a email this time.

Comment: you need to check `$_POST` is `!empty` to only execute php code when form is getting submit. Let me update my answer code

Comment: While this is a valid edit, I don't understand why you chose to use `=== false` when you simply could have removed the `!`.  It will return the email if it's valid, or false if it's not, so by adding `=== false` just seems superfluous.

Comment: Still is red when loaded not when invalidly submitted. Also the button directs you to the top of the page still. Also one more question, how I can I keep the text already in there and just make that text red.

Comment: @bc2946088 you can visit here to verify your php validation logic (https://www.w3schools.com/php/filter_validate_email.asp)

Comment: @Matt.Owen Are you sure you added `if (isset($_POST) && !empty($_POST)) {` this `if`  statement at the top of your php code?

Comment: You really should use a better resource...  http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php @MaheshSinghChouhan  --

Comment: Yup! i visited your website link and there is no red color text on contact form, also if you want to ignore page refreshing to the same page you can use `jquery ajax`  function to submit your form and handle the request without refreshing page, let me know if you want `ajax` function code to submit your form also.

Comment: Click the email input and type something, the text is red. I have never worked with ajax, so if there is a way through query or something I would use it then

Comment: Tried, still text is black. Ok there might be caching on your browser, i will suggest you to use incognito window or other browser to check

Comment: Yep. It was just caching on my browser. But what about keeping the text there, rather than it being removed if the email is invalid

Comment: For that you need `jquery ajax` function to prevent your page to reload when submitting the form, or you can use `<input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" name="email" id="email-input" required value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>">`  to get the posted value after form submitted

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139664/discussion-between-matt-owen-and-mahesh-singh-chouhan).